# rewriting urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I need to do is change the links on my website, for example from

> www.mywebsite.com/index.php
>
> www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=about_us

to

> www.myswebsite.com/index.html
>
> www.myswebsite.com/about_us.html

I was told *htaccess* was used to acheive this and I presume this is achieved with some sort of regular expression.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Well as you can see by the title i didnt quite know how to word it and find what i needed... with no thanks to you i had a brainwave and typed in module-rewrite and now finally getting somewhere...

Comment: lol dont be mean, it's ok we've all been through it. He's a new user. Dont worry about it. Riskeh, make sure you try doing some extensive research yourself as well when before posting a question. After you have exhausted everything you can think of.

Comment: dont worry ive posted something for you.

Comment: thank you very much pavan and will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

you have

www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=about_us

and you want

www.myswebsite.com/about_us.html

in your `.htaccess` file add a line to the end of this file:

```
redirect /about_us http://www.myswebsite.com/about_us.html
```

voila

http://affiliate-minder.com/internetmarketing/using-htaccess-file-for-affiliate-link-redirects/

**PK**

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the rewrite engine. The RewriteRule will fetch the page in the second parameter when the first parameter is called. So `www.myswebsite.com/about_us.html` will load `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?action=about_us`, but the URL in the address bar will still be `www.myswebsite.com/about_us.html`. The `[NC]` at the end just makes it case insensitive.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/about_us\.html$ index.php?action=about_us [NC]
```

More info:
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckSpelling on
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$\.html /index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and from there, you could use `index.php` to either navigate, or just display the content