# Simple userprofile-URL without rewriting addressrule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website with a lot of profiles. What I want is that you can simply navigate to one of those profiles with a URL like www.mywebsite.com/userX (just like twitter with twitter.com/userX).

I already know how this is possible by using the .htaccess and rewriterule, but the problem is it changes the entirely URL to something like www.mywebsite.com/?username=userX. It must just load a specific PHP-file without rewriting the URL in the addressbar.

Who knows how I can perform this?

(p.s. sorry for my average English)

Comment: Did you try to research this topic - or at least to use search at this site? Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868055/rewriting-urls-with-htaccess), for example; actually, there's a plenty of similar questions here. In short, a server should _rewrite_, not redirect.

Comment: O well, excuse me, I tried it with a simple rewrite, but that didn't work so I thought the rewrite-function was not the function I had to use. But now I tried a more complex rewrite and it worked well. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

See the fine article:

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls

It explains that yeah, you want a mod_rewrite (placed in an .htaccess file) rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)\.html /news.php?news_id=$1

And this maps requests from

/news.php?news_id=63

to

/news/63.html
```

Another possibility is doing it with forcetype, which forces anything down a particular path to use php to eval the content. So, in your .htaccess file, put the following:

```
<Files news>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

And then the index.php can take action based on the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    // outputs '/63.html'
?>
```